# Symfony2 populating select list options with data from DB

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to populate a select list, with data from an entity.
The options, are created correctly, and values of options are correct.

However, everytime i submit the form it always put the original value of debtorGroup, and ignores the selected value from the form

An example of the post data: 
(Selected debtorGroup was 3, not 2 which was the original value)

```
object(App\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Customer)[449]
 protected 'id' => int 9
 private 'debtorGroup' => int 2
 private 'fullName' => string 'Daniel Mensing' (length=20)
```

My FormBuilder code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($customer)
        ->add('debtorGroup', 'entity', array(
            'mapped'   => false,
            'class' => 'AppCoreBundle:DebtorGroup',
            'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('fullName')
        ->add('companyName')
        ->add('address1')
        ->add('address2', 'text', array(
            'required'  => false,
        ))
        ->add('zipPostal')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('email')
        ->getForm();
```

My Customer entity:

```
class Customer extends User
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="debtor_group", type="integer")
 */
private $debtorGroup;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="full_name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $fullName;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="company_name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $companyName = null;
```

And my DebtorGroup Entity:

```
class DebtorGroup
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;
}
```

Anyone has a clue whats wrong?

Thanks in advance,

/Daniel

Comment: I got it working like this
    `add('debtorGroup', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppCoreBundle:DebtorGroup')
    ->findAll()
    ))`

But are there any smarter/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have `mapped` set to false in your entity field declaration. This is what the documentation says about the `mapped` option:

> If you wish the field to be ignored when reading or writing to the
>   object, you can set the mapped option to false.

Sounds a lot like the problem you're having.